# Which "useless" programs I can remove from Autostart without drawbacks?

Tags: kubuntu, lubuntu, startup, autostart

The autostart programs placed in etc/xdg/autostart/ are these ones:
Which "useless" programs I can remove from Autostart without drawbacks?
Why I have two times "screensaver"? I needed?
Note that I have installed Kubuntu (over Lubuntu).
I need lubuntu apps that do not exist on kubuntu.

```
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/baloo_file.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-copy-worker.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-welcome-tour.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/gsettings-data-convert.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/kdeconnectd.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/klipper.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/krunner.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/lxpolkit.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-desktop.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-notifications.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-policykit-agent.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-powermanagement.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-qlipper-autostart.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-xscreensaver-autostart.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/mpd.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/orca-autostart.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.korgac.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.plasmashell.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/pam_kwallet_init.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/powerdevil.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/print-applet.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/screensaver.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/snap-userd-autostart.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/spice-vdagent.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/unity-fallback-mount-helper.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/unity-settings-daemon.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/xdg-user-dirs.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/xembedsniproxy.desktop
file:///etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop
```

Comment: Looks like you did not remove your Kubuntu packages.

Comment: but i work on kubuntu.... placed on lubuntu... i have the start screen of lubuntu... and then kubuntu appears.

Comment: Please be careful to adjust any comments/answers you get to ensure they match your *unstated* release.  The packagers of systems (Lubuntu & Kubuntu) make changes each cycle, as given we don't know yours, you need to adjust any comments/answers which will of course be general in nature, or specific to a *guessed* or *known* release which may not be yours. I'm aware of many Lubuntu changes but I'm not going to guess your release from what you've provided..  so do your own checks before implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These programs are programs which the developers consider a useful addition to the desktop experience. Which are useless depends on the user, you. We cannot indicate which of these would be useless to you. I'd leave them alone.

With respect to multiple "screensavers", "org.gnome" launchers and "lxqt" launchers, these indicate that you have been creative with your system, installing different desktop environments. Do not worry, several of these autostart programs are only loaded with the desktop environment with which they came.

One could think you can get rid of the autostarters by uninstalling an installed desktop environment. Unfortunately, that is not easy. The reason why it is difficult is because many of the main packages that are pulled in while installing a desktop environment are actually marked as "manually installed". That prevents you from taking the whole system down would you ever remove the metapackage used to install the desktop environment. On the other hand, that also prevents you from automatically and granularly removing an entire desktop environment just by removing the metapackage followed by a `sudo apt autoremove`.

These extra files take some space on your hard drive, but otherwise will not in any way affect the performance of your system. I would leave them there. One day, you will reinstall fresh, and then it will all be cleaned up.

Comment: So I can remove lxqt-xscreensaver-autostart.desktop without any significant other influence on the system / desktop? What this does?